# Momentum conservation isolated system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, everyday-life, velocity

> An isolated rail car originally moving with velocity $v_°$ on a straight frictionless level track contains large amount of sand.A release valve on the bottom of the car malfunctions and sand begins to pour out straight down relative to the rail car.Then what happens to the speed of the car?

The answer says it remains same but if the speed remains same wont it be violation of conservation of momentum . I believe it should increase

The word isolated rail gives me  a confusion as to what it means

Comment: How are you removing the coaches

Comment: Why would uncoupling a coach make it lose ke and move away from the others?

Comment: Please do not heavily edit questions so that answers become invalid or confusing

Answer (score 1):

like i was looking at the title it said "isolated" but you removed the coaches and didn't mentioned what happened to them and who did this.so this system is not isolated at all first of all. and secondly as you said initially main coach was moving with constant speed so there is no force on it but after you removed all other coaches it is moving with same speed as there is no net force now and nor did any force act on it during the process of removal of other coaches. so, congrats law of conservation of momentum is conserved in this situation.

Answer (score -1):

When you remove the coaches, you're exerting external force on the system. This means that the system is no longer isolated.

Comment: Unless the system is the entire train and the coaches are "removed" by internal forces. I think the OP needs to clarify many things before a sufficient answer can be made.

Comment: @AaronStevens If the coaches are removed using internal forces, then momentum is transferred between coaches, so the main coach is unlikely to be at the same velocity unless the removal was specifically contrived to cause this. If the coaches were detached without momentum transfer, then they would still be moving with the main coach and aren't really "removed" since they don't go anywhere in the rest frame of the main coach.

Comment: Simply the nail connecting two compartments is loosened and coaches separate